# Broken image when using Image/Barcode to generate barcodes in DOMPdf

Tags: php, pdf, pear, barcode, dompdf

I'm trying to debug a problem we are having with a barcode in a pdf generated by DOMPdf.
The image works most of the time but 1 in every 10 tries results in a lesser quality image

[image: Broken barcode image]

I have tried changing everything i can think of but without results. Has anyone ever encountered this problem and fixed it? I can't reproduce the broken image on my local machine, it only occurs in our live server.

We are running the latest DOMPdf on a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with all updates.
The pdf i streamed to the user using the ->stream() function in DOMPdf

Comment: Compare a pdf generated on your local machine with one produced on the server, where the server one has the bad image in it. Figuring out the difference between the two should help figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: I've not seen this before, could be a GD problem maybe? As indicated by @MarcB it might help to see a version of the PDF with and without the corruption.

Comment: have you got any solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I recommend to store the raw barcode images that were generated separately. Check if any of them contains the corruption, or if it's just the PDF that contains the corrupted barcode images.

Also use a tool like `pdfimages` from the `poppler-utils` package to extract the barcode image from the pdf. Check if they contain the corruption, or if the PDF rendering is broken.